# move an object (spritenode) in swift continously until touched on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, touchesbegan, touches

i am trying to get an object to perform an action continuously until it is touched, but when touched the object just performs the action once.
 
this is what i have got to so far

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touches: AnyObject in touches {

        plane.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        plane.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 500))
    }
}
```

any sugessiton how to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move an object, you better use `SKAction.moveBy` instead of an impulse. At the moment you only execute that action if the user touched the screen. If you want to run an action **until** the user touches the screen, you have to put it in the `didMoveToView` method and use a key so you can remove the action from the sprite:

```
class YourClass: SKScene{
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //4 seconds for 500y
        var neededTime:NSTimeInterval = 4
        var action = SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(0, 500), duration: neededTime)
        var repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(action)



        //Repeat the action forever and with a key so you can remove it on touch:
        sprite.runAction(repeatAction, withKey: "aKey")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        //remove the action
        sprite.removeActionForKey("aKey")
    }
}
```